# Redis Charting for Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I have a Rails application, it's uses Redis for storing stats, hits and counts as key, value format. How can I represent stored keys as chart?

Comment: $redis.keys output;
c:1:127.0.0.1:hourly 
(to store c object, referrer, hourly)

Answer (score 0):

Rails doesn't have any particular charting tools built in. I've heard of people having great success with libraries such as [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/), however. Perhaps take a look into using that to create the data.